# Parent gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid view " GridViewTtransmittals" with 2 child grid view

```
Child 1: GridViewTranstoCon (parent GridViewEfile) 
Child 2: GridViewEfile
```

GridViewEfile (child2) itself is child of child1 " GridViewEfile"
Now I like to define GridViewEfile_RowDeleting but I have error (GridViewTranstoCon' does not exist in the current context)
Please help what is the problem?

```
 protected void GridViewEfile_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
     GridView Efile = sender as GridView;
    var parentrow1 = (GridViewRow)Efile.Parent.Parent;
    var parentrow2 = (GridViewRow)Efile.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    //  int transid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewTtransmittals.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    int transid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewTtransmittals.DataKeys[parentrow2.RowIndex].Value);

    GridView GridViewTranstoCon = GridViewTtransmittals.FindControl("GridViewTranstoCon") as GridView;

    int transmittoconid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewTranstoCon.DataKeys[parentrow1.RowIndex].Value);
    int FileId = Convert.ToInt32(Efile.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

    //Also step into this and see what it's doing
    OnDeleteEfile(FileId, transmittoconid, transid);
}
```

Markup is like below:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTtransmittals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          BorderStyle="None" ShowHeader="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="TransID"  onrowdatabound="GridViewTtransmittals_RowDataBound"
        onrowdeleting="GridViewTtransmittals_RowDeleting">
          <columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Transmittal" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />

                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:hyperlinkfield DataNavigateUrlFields="TransId" 
              DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Copy of Transmittal.aspx?TransId={0}" DataTextField="TRANSMITTAL" 
              HeaderText="Transmittal" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "TRANSMITtoCon">
<ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTranstoCon" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    ForeColor="#000000" GridLines="Both" onrowdeleting="GridViewTranstoCon_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="TransmittoconID">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
                    <Columns>
                      <asp:BoundField DataField="TRANSMITtoCon" HeaderText= "TRANSMITtoCon" >
                       <ItemStyle Width = "20%" />
                      </asp:BoundField>
                      <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                     </Columns>
                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "E-FILES">
<ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:GridView ID="GridViewEfile" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    ForeColor="#000000" GridLines="Both"  DataKeyNames="FileID">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
                    <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "E-FILES">
                  <ItemTemplate>

                      <asp:LinkButton HeaderText = "E-FILES" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FileID")%>'><%#Eval("FileName")%> </asp:LinkButton>

                       </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />

                     </Columns>
                     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



             </columns>
```

Comment: You should have to use `FindControl` method to have references of  `GridView` controls.

Comment: thanks i used findcontrol and change the code, now my question is about var parentrow1, var parentrow2 are they correct?